# Convert MySQL query into JSON object via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a problem modifying and converting a PHP array to a JSON object; the array forms via a MySQL query.

The desired JSON format is as follows:

```
[{
    "id":101,
    "text":"Bank / Kas",
    "children":[{
        "id":101.1,
        "text":"Bank",
        "children":[{
            "id":101.11,
            "text":"Bank Bca",
            "children":[{
                "id":101.111,
                "text":"Bank Sayangan"
                }]
        },{
            "id":101.12,
            "text":"Bank BNI"
        }]
    },{
        "id":101.2,
        "text":"Kas",
        "state":"closed",
        "children":[{
            "id":101.21,
            "text":"Kas Besar"
        },{
            "id":101.22,
            "text":"Kas Kecil"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Can you post your PHP/SQL and your current output? You can click [edit] to modify your question.

Comment: what's the problem with converting to json? `echo json_encode($array)` is all you need. Most likely you should be saying you're having trouble **BUILDING** that array.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to do it :

```
$data = $table->fetchAll();
return json_encode($data);
```